# Special Characters in WCF REST parameter

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, uri

In my REST service, it is required to take parameters having special characters like Ä, Å etc.

The problem is that such characters get converted to "?" by the time it hits the method and gets assigned to the variable. While debugging, I can see that the **IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.RequestUri** has the correct value but **IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.QueryParameters** has "?"

The UriTemplate looks like this: **/stores?city={city}** and values like **/stores?city=BOLLNÄS** doesn't work.

Any pointers on how to handle these characters in input would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the main problem here can be that those special characters are not valid in URL and you must encode them. Try this: `/stores?city=BOLLN%C3%84S`

Comment: In fact this was a tool related issue. I was using soapUI to test the services and the tool automatically converted Ä to %C4 and hence the service was failing. Still, not completedly convinced why the service could not figure it out if the debugger could